# How to integrate Excel VSTO Ribbon with a scheduler?

Tags: c#, vsto, quartz-scheduler, scheduler, quartz.net

I am designing an Excel Ribbon with VSTO. One of the functionalities that I want is that all users of this ribbon will be running a scheduler in the background if they click a button, so that an action can be performed at certain times (as specified in my code). I am using Quartz scheduler in C# VSTO.

The following is some of my code.

```
private void myButton_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
            StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler().Start();
            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<myJob>().Build();

            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("myJob", "mJ")
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => 
                  x.WithIntervalInSeconds(5).RepeatForever())
                .Build();

}
```

In other words, if a user clicks, I want a scheduler to be configured to run myJob (defined in a class myJob), every 5 seconds.

But I get the following exceptions which I cannot understand and my action is not performed.

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in mscorlib.dll
>   'excel.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: proj.vsto|vstolocal): Loaded
>
> Exception thrown:
>   'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in
>   Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.Implementation.dll

Comment: When exactly do you get that exception? If you add a try-catch around the event, does the caught exception tell you anything more?

Comment: I get those exceptions when I click on the button represented by `myButton_Click()`. I wrapped the code sample as well as the job in a try-catch block but I did not get any more info.